# Saving array field in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

folks - I'm trying to save an array field in MongoDB, and it doesn't want to save properly.

I'm trying to build a trivia-hosting app. The API endpoint in question will allow the host to take each response received for each question in a round, and determine if it should receive full credit, no credit, or something in between. My round document looks like this:

```
{
    "_id":{"$oid":"6067c6c7c1821e3db0530eb9"},
    "type":"general",
    "game ":{"$oid":"6067c666c1821e3db0530eb7"},
    "questions":[
        {
            "text":"What is the capital of Finland?",
            "answer":"Helsinki",
            "value":2,
            "key":[],
            "number":1
        },
        {
            "text":"What is the capital of Kazakhstan?",
            "answer":"Nursultan",
            "value":2,
            "key":[],
            "number":2
        }
    ],
    "title":"My test round",
    "description":"This describes my test round.",
    "settings":{
        "endBonus":false,
        "maxWager":0,
        "releaseQuestions":false,
        "answerAfterEach":false
    },
    "owner":{"$oid":"605271517fce7249cc8eb436"},
    "__v":3
}
```

The req.body looks like this:

```
{
    "key": [
        {
            "answer":"Helsinki",
            "key":[
                {
                    "answer":"helsinki",
                    "correct": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "answer":"Nursultan",
            "key":[
                {
                    "answer":"nursultan",
                    "correct": 1
                },
                {
                    "answer":"nur-sultan",
                    "correct": 1
                },
                {
                    "answer":"astana",
                    "correct": 0.5
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the code to update the key for each question:

```
exports.gradeRound = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const r = await Round.findById(req.params.rid);
  //for each question in the round
  let newKey;
  for (var i = 0; i < r.questions.length; i++) {
    console.log(`Question ${i + 1} info:`);
    console.log(r.questions[i]);
    console.log();

    console.log(`Key ${i + 1}:`);
    console.log(req.body.key[i].key);
    console.log();

    // ...some deleted code that verifies that the correct question
    // ...is being graded...that part works fine.

    // copy the array from req.body and set the key array for the question
    // The code commented below are other ways I've tried to set the array.

    // req.body.key[i].key.forEach((a) => {
    //   r.questions[i].key.push(a);
    // });

    // r.questions[i].key = req.body.key[i].key;

    newKey = req.body.key[i].key.slice();
    newKey.forEach((el) => {
      r.questions[i].key.push({ ...el });
      console.log(r.questions[i].key);
    });
  }

  const ans = await r.save();

  // this logged the document with empty keys for each question.
  // const newR = await Round.findById(req.params.rid);
  // console.log(newR);

  // ...yet this gave what I would have expected for ans...the round with the 
  // keys populated
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: ans,
  });
});
```

The funny thing is, every console.log gives me what I would've expected. The response comes back with what I expect - the key arrays in the "ans" object are populated with the exact values from req.body. However, when I query the data again (as you can see from the commented-out code below r.save()), none of the keys are populated, and this was also the case when I looked in MongoDBCompass.

I'm pulling my hair out here - what did I do wrong? Or is there some minor detail that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating -

So apparently, Mongoose isn't looking deep enough to see that this array field is changed (since it's embedded in an object in an array in the main document), so to force it to save, I added this line right above r.save():

```
r.markModified('questions');
```

Then, when I do

```
const ans = await r.save();
```

...it sees that 'questions' was modified and saves it.